# BigDecimal and rounding

Tags: java

I have been looking for answers here re: rounding and BigDecimal, but I am having trouble. Can someone help?

The actual result of the below division is 11.469...

```
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(0.32);
        
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(2.79);
        
        BigDecimal diffPercent = (a.divide(b, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)).multiply(HUNDRED);  // 11.00
        BigDecimal diffPercent = (a.divide(b, 4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)).multiply(HUNDRED);  // 11.4700
```

How can I get 11.47 (two decimal places)?

Comment: Using `.stripTrailingZeros()` would work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of multiplying by BigDecimal(100), move the decimal point to the right:

```
BigDecimal diffPercent = (a.divide(b, 4, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)).movePointRight(2)
```

Output: 11.47

This works because moving the decimal point only adjusts the *scale* of the BigDecimal.

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal bg = new BigDecimal("11.468");
MathContext mc = new MathContext(3); // 3 precision

// bg1 is rounded using mc
final BigDecimal round = bg.round(mc, RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(round);
```

Posting as this is another example of how to round